# Can I say 'it will be hard for the society to make any progress'?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> Ambition is indispensable for both individuals and the society.
>   Without the ambition of pursuing success, people may feel empty and
>   meaningless in their lives, and it will be hard for the society to
>   make any progress.

Is

> ... it will be hard for the society to make any progress

correct?

I am not sure whether it is because **society** is not a person, so I am not sure whether I can use **make progress** after it.

Thank you!

Comment: A person is not required as the subject of the verb **make.** Please ask a specific question about usage; you are more likely to receive a useful answer if you do. We can't serve as a rewrite desk, though!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the question is: is '… it will be hard for the society to make any progress' correct?

Comment: Yes. It is correct.

Comment: @Emma, we do have ambition, so if you hypothesize about not having it, you should use **would** rather than **will**.  For example,  "Without the ambition... it **would** be hard for society to make any progress". Arguably, you should also use **might** rather than **may**,

Comment: If you talk about _the society_ you are unambiguously referring to a particular society (eg the Philological Society, or the Society for the Protection of Ancient Buildings). I think you mean "society" without an articloe.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @PEDant, **"society"** and **"make progress"** can be associated without any problem.

---

As mentioned by @JavaLatte, **may** and **will** must match. So you can say:

> people **will** feel empty... and it **will** be hard for the society...

or:

> people **may** feel empty... and it **would** be hard for the society...

I cannot guarantee if **might** is more suitable than **may** in the sentence above.

---

However, I think that **the most correct** way to tell it is:

> people **would** feel empty... and it **would** be hard for the society...

or:

> people **might** feel empty... and it **might** be hard for the society...